# Background image contrast and colors render very different between browsers

Tags: image, browser

I'm having a bit of trouble with some images rendering differently in different browsers. As you can see in the images, the background is very different in all 4 different browsers. All browsers are up-to-date, but Safari is by far the worst of them all. And it is actually worse when you look at the website instead of the screenshots. But you get the point.

My question is, why is there so much difference? And can it be fixed.

And the CSS is:

```
body {
background:url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center top fixed;
background-size:cover; 
-moz-background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-khtml-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-color:#000000;
font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

}

[image: Firefox]
[image: Chrome]
[image: IE 10]
[image: Safari]

Comment: Pictures mean almost nothing without the code.

Comment: Sorry, I have now edited it, so the code is now included.

Comment: Do you mean the difference in color? One being slightly darker than the other?

Comment: Try throwing your image up on the wall with a projector.  You'll see some serious color variation.

Comment: Yes, the color difference for one.
But, at my computer at least, it looks like the one from Safari has quality very low compared to the rest. Like you are saving an imagine with quality 4 in Photoshop, and the rest is 10 or something.
But it sounds as though there is nothing to do ?